# In ggplot, how to create line visualization with pointy edges (like "toothpicks")?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking for a way to create lines with `ggplot()` that have "pointy" edges, to get an overall look of "toothpicks".

For example, consider the following visualization:

```r
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

my_df <-
  tribble(~name, ~value,
        "a", 1,
        "a", 2,
        "b", 1,
        "b", 2)


my_df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.5, lineend = "round") +
  expand_limits(y = c(0.5, 2.5)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

Now, let's say I set

```r
y_top    <- 1.75
y_bottom <- 1.25
```

as the values from which the lines start to get "sharpened".

How can I get something similar to:

[image: thoothpicks]

Although it would be ideal to also have the fade-out effect, the "toothpick" look is most important to me. Unfortunately, `geom_lines()`'s `lineend` argument doesn't support the "pointiness" I'm looking for.

Any idea how this could be achieved?

Thanks!

Comment: just curious graphically is there a reason for this? or is this simply for aesthetics?

Comment: @Mike, mostly aesthetics. I want to represent a line that extends beyond what we see when we use `coord_cartesian()` to zoom in.

Comment: To show data (i.e. the vertical line) goes below the axis, couldn't you put an arrow head on the line where it meets the x axis?

Comment: @MarkNeal, yes, that would be one option. Indeed this is a visual design discussion, and my specific design choice is what driving this question.

Comment: I think there is a good discussion to be had about the “best ways” to show data goes beyond the axes. I guess my impression is that a thinner geometry (like in a violin plot) is suggesting less data in that direction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way is using the `ggforce` package to access some "tweened" geoms which vary in appearance along their length, like `geom_link2`. Here, I do some prep work to add observations that are 0.25 in from the extremes for each name, and to assign widths depending on whether we're at an extreme or not.

```
library(tidyverse); library(ggforce)
my_df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarize(min_val = min(value), max_val = max(value)) %>%
  mutate(min_taper = min_val + 0.25, max_taper = max_val - 0.25) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-name, names_to = "step") %>%
  mutate(width = if_else(str_detect(step, "val"), 0, 1)) %>%
  arrange(name, value) %>%

#Here's what it looks like at this point:
## A tibble: 8 x 4
#  name  step      value width
#  <chr> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a     min_val    1        0
#2 a     min_taper  1.25     1
#3 a     max_taper  1.75     1
#4 a     max_val    2        0
#5 b     min_val    1        0
#6 b     min_taper  1.25     1
#7 b     max_taper  1.75     1
#8 b     max_val    2        0
  
  # now that it's prepped, it's a short call in ggplot2/ggforce:
  ggplot(aes(name, value, size = width)) +
  ggforce::geom_link2() +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(0,0.6)) +  # controls width range of lines 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I don't get the same plot as yours when running your code. [See here what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kOLp.png). Could you please answer via reprex?

Comment: Hmm, that's curious. I get the same output using reprex. I'm using R 4.1.0 on macOS running 10.16, tidyverse 1.3.1, ggplot2 3.3.5 and ggforce 0.3.3.

Comment: 0) Do things look any different if you use a wider size range e.g. `scale_size_continuous(range = c(0,5)) +`?  1) does your prepared data look like mine if you remove the pipe %>% after the `arrange` line?   2) What version of `ggforce` do you have loaded?  3) Perhaps a rendering issue? If using RStudio, what graphics device is loaded in Global Options - General - Graphics?

Comment: I use a Windows machine. I had to change the graphics device to AGG for this to render it properly. But it works! Thank you.

Comment: Jon: I want to solve the problem with graphics device, because using `AGG` causes strange text rendering on my machine. So on the one hand, I need AGG for this toothpicks plot, but otherwise I need the default rendering (which fails the toothpicks). So my problem is that I need renderings to coexist! Is this worth posting a new question at Stack Overflow or rather open an issue on whatever package's github?

Comment: Not sure. I've had problems with the windows plot preview which were sometimes resolved when I used `ggsave(filename = "my_plot.png", ..., dpi = 300, type = "cairo")` It might also be worth opening an issue with AGG, as one of its main goals is to ease text rendering.